# Prevent image resizing with browser zoom in zoom out javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, resize, position

I am new to javascript and i am trying to create a game in that. I have placed an image but when i resize the browser like zoom in and zoom out with CTRL + or CTRL -, the position and size of my image also changes according to it. i want my image's position and size to be fixed. I am trying to find the answer on google but haven't found a single one working for me yet. Any help would be appreciated. i want to fix the postion and size of image with id "bb1".

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

.bg {
/* The image used */
background-image: url("Assets/Game_Background.png");

/* Full height */
height: 100%; 
width: 100%;

/* Center and scale the image nicely */
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover; 
}
</style>
<title>Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg">
<button  onclick="window.location.href='Main_Menu.html';" style="position: relative; ;background- 
color: rgba(0,0,255,0); outline: none; border: none;   opacity: 1;transform: translate(500px,220px); 
width: 150px; height: 80px; "><font size="4" color="White"></font></button>
<div class="imageWrapper" style="transform: translate(700px,200px);" >
<img class="overlayImage" id="bb1" src="Assets/Marble_Blue.png"  style="position: absolute; display: 
block; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1; width: 26px; height: 26px;  transform: translate(246px, 37px); 
position: absolute;">
</div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my suggestion is to learn more CSS first since from what you said here, it's more like css problem and to be honest it's a bit hard to see since your css is scattered like that (there's <style>, css file, and inline), keep it clean first as a file (say style.css), so you can debug easily.

Comment: @mfakhrusy so you mean, style and css file both shouldn't come together? something like that?

Comment: Yes, it would be better to have one source of styling, so it's easier to debug like on your case, you probably would have an easier time figuring this problem by your own if you have a clean css source.

Answer (score 0):

remove the css property background-size: cover; because that resizes your image when you change your window size (to fit the container)

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: i removed the cover property, now it has started resizing and i don't want it to resize at all. The background is working perfect with cover property as it is not resizing when i zoom in or zoom out the browser, the problem is with the image with id "bb1 ", you can see in my code, that image resizes when i zoom in or zoom out the browser.